# JavaScript total number of pages to be printed?

Tags: javascript, printing

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

```html
<div id="printableArea">
  <h1>Print me</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div!" /> M
```

It's work fine, but Other buttons don't work when closed print the page.
This is not the main problem.
How to get the total number of pages to be printed? This problem
very important to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate number of pages which will print using Javascript window.print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709806/calculate-number-of-pages-which-will-print-using-javascript-window-print)

Comment: Nobody don't knows?